# C# Action Delegates and EF Repository Scope Issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scope, delegates, repository

I have a Wrapper method on a WebApi Controller that exposes and Action Delegate. I use it to talk to the service layer. The Action passes a UnitOfWork that has my EF Repositories for the models

The problem is when I try populate a model passed from the controller to service, the changes, while they apply at the service layer, do not reflect on the Controller. However the commented out approach does work and I do not understand why

```
  //In controller
   Unit(uw =>  officeService.Get3(uw, user, User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString()));
        return Ok(user);
  //the returned user does not have changes applied

 //Service
 public void Get3(UnitOfWork uw, Member model, string id, string include = null)
    {
            object m = uw.MemberRepository.Get(u => u.UserId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            model = (Member)m;
            //model.Created = m.Created;
            //model.ExpiryInDays = m.ExpiryInDays;
            // and so on...
    }
```

Comment: `Action` doesn't return anything and you're not passing it by `ref`. You can make the `Action` a `Func<>` and return the model back to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to `model` is passed by value, so changing assigning to `model` in `Get3` won't have any effect on the caller.   You can either pass by ref:

```
public void Get3(UnitOfWork uw, ref Member model, string id, string include = null)
```

Or return it (as you seem to be ignoring the parameter anyway).

```
public Member Get3(UnitOfWork uw, string id, string include = null)
{
    // ...
    return model;
}
```

This would require an overload of `Unit` that accepts a `Func` and returns the result.

Comment: You forgot the `Member` parameter in the `Get3` method

Comment: @MarkC. I removed it deliberately. As noted in the answer, it isn't actually used in the method.

Comment: `model = (Member)m;` looks  like he was trying to update the properties on it.. so I wouldn't say it's not used, just used incorrectly

Comment: the ref keyword works and fits my overall goal nice. I do not want to use return. Member is a reference type though so I didn't think to use ref. And my apologies I posted an older test when I was not sure if Member was coming over as Value or not. Thanks all for the speedy help